# PDFBox throwing index out of bounds exception while extracting fonts

Tags: java, pdf

I am using pdfbox version 1.8.3 to extract fonts from PDFs. For a few of the PDFs, sometimes, I am receiving an InexOutOfBounds exception. This is the stacktrace for the same:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2218, Size: 0  
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessBuffer.seek(RandomAccessBuffer.java:84)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessFileInputStream.read(RandomAccessFileInputStream.java:96)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
    at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:139)
    at org.apache.fontbox.cmap.CMapParser.parseNextToken(CMapParser.java:386)
    at org.apache.fontbox.cmap.CMapParser.parse(CMapParser.java:118)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.parseCmap(PDFont.java:602)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont.extractToUnicodeEncoding(PDSimpleFont.java:458)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont.determineEncoding(PDSimpleFont.java:426)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font.determineEncoding(PDType1Font.java:269)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.<init>(PDFont.java:193)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont.<init>(PDSimpleFont.java:88)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font.<init>(PDType1Font.java:152)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFontFactory.createFont(PDFontFactory.java:92)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources.getFonts(PDResources.java:204)
```

This is not an issue with the PDF file itself. The exception arises sporadically - for the same PDF, sometimes I am getting an exception and sometimes not.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *for the same PDF, sometimes I am getting an exception and sometimes not.* - that sounds like a bug in your code. If you share enough code for us to reproduce the issue, we might help you further.

Comment: Current PDFBox versions are 1.8.13 and 2.0.7. Note that you should not run parallel threads on the same PDDocument.